# Getting syntax error in php

Tags: php, string, if-statement, parse-error

while using if statement as below and assigning values to two variable I'm getting below error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Guar' (T_STRING) in /home/..../.../something.php on line 158. below is the code of line 157 and 158.
I know I need to use some escape character but I don't know how to implement it here. Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Code:

```
if($crom_name== "Groundnut pods (raw)"){$guname="DUO/LGL ;L\UM sSFRLf";$hiname="D}\UO,L SL Ol,IM\";}
if($crom_name== "Guar"){$guname="U]JFZ";$hiname="S,:8Z";}
```

Comment: this code works fine as written. if there is a parse error there is likely an unterminated string somewhere earlier in the code, so you have to post the whole thing

Comment: If the rest of your code is compacted that way and entirely unspaced/unindented, you'll never find the source of your issues.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Please share complete code, may be problem in somewhere else.

Comment: if($crom_name== "Groundnut pods (raw)"){$guname="DUO/LGL ;L\UM sSFRLf";$hiname="D}\UO,L SL Ol,IM\";} This line is at 157.

Comment: I think there is problem in 157, as it contains brace in string.

Comment: `if($crom_name== "Groundnut pods (raw)")
{
$guname="DUO/LGL ;L\UM sSFRLf";
$hiname="D}\UO,L SL Ol,IM\";
} `

In you last line add double `\\` in place of single `\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
if($crom_name== "Groundnut pods (raw)"){$guname="DUO/LGL ;L\UM sSFRLf";$hiname="D}\UO,L SL Ol,IM\";}
```

You are escaping the final quote and therefore the line should be throwing an unterminated string constant error.  You need to escape the backslash.  You probably also want to escape the other backslash (the one before the U.

```
if($crom_name== "Groundnut pods (raw)"){$guname="DUO/LGL ;L\\UM sSFRLf";$hiname="D}\\UO,L SL Ol,IM\\";}
```